# Pdf file displayed in ipad simulator not in Ipad device

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I have a pdf file in resources folder of my Universal app. with my coding It is displayed on Ipad Simulaor, Iphone simulator and on iphone device but that file is not displayed on Ipad device, can anyone suggest me how to resolve it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: where do you view the PDF? UIWebView?

Answer (score 1):

The first thing to check is whether you are accessing the PDF using the exact name as it is stored in the filesystem. The normal OS X filesystem is case-insensitive, while the filesystem on the device is case-sensitive; this means that e.g. "foo.pdf" and "foo.PDF" are the same in the simulator, but are different on the device.

If that doesn't fix it, check the console for error messages and edit your question to include any that are output.